# Setting default value on a field?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009, aot

I'm adding a new field to an existing **Table** (not a "core" one, but one that was created by an inhouse dev previously) and I'm trying to set a default value for it.

I created a field of type **Int**, but now by default it's all 0's for the records that are already there.

Is there any way to define a default value for that field, for all the existing records and to be inserted records ?

Ultimately, what I'm trying to achieve is that I want a configurable field (ShowOnReport) so certain records won't show up in a **Web Report.** Right now, I want this field to default to 1 to all existing records, and later, switch them to 0 depending on business needs.

Maybe I've got the termininology wrong, but Google and Bing are mute to me regarding this... :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description I think your field should be of type `NoYesId` which is similar to a boolean but is rendered as a check box per default.

For a default value you should overwrite the table method `initValue` and set your field to `NoYes::Yes` - this ensures the default value for all new records. For your existing records you have to write a simple AOT Job which sets `NoYes::Yes` to your field via `update_recordset`.

Comment: Sounds good. But I seem limited in terms of field types I can create. Do I need to turn on "advanced" developer mode or something ? http://i.imgur.com/xnIXsdZ.jpg EDIT: Ah, I created a field of type Enum and chose the Enum Type NoYesCombo, which is how it is called in AX 2009.

Answer (score 2):

Try to override initValue method in your table. Give code, for example :

```
public void initValue()
{
  this.TestDefaultValue = 1;
}
```

Hope this help