# How to change realEdit field's default realValue property?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have set the realValue property of Grid's realEdit field from 0.00 to 1.00

What I want to achieve is that when I add new record in Grid I want the realEdit field to be 1 by default, not 0.00.

[image]

But it still shows 0.00. Is not it the right properties to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your real control is bound to a field, then set the value in the `initValue` method of the table (or in the datasource) as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293147/setting-default-value-on-a-field/20321029#20321029).

```
public void initValue()
{
  this.TestDefaultValue = 1;
}
```

If not bound, consider using a display method or setting the value at runtime:

```
realEdit.realValue(3.14);
```